# *911 ** help! Does Apple developer program require latest iphone for developing iphone Apps?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, mobile

**Do we require latest iphone model 6 or 6 plus to test apps or any model of iphone will do just fine ?**

Hi I am new to the Apple ecosystem and trying to learn to make apps. Although i have coded simple games like classic snake and ran it on my iphone 4 as it gives us real time info on how well the apps is doing on a device.

Since Iphone 6 and 6 plus have launched and has lots of improved features, i wanted to know from a developer perspective that any device like iphone 4, iphone 4s or 5s will do for creating simple apps and deploy in the app store? OR do i have to have a latest iphone 6 or 6 plus.

***question 2 : What role does a device plays (iphones and not simulators) when it comes developing and testing Iphone Apps??***

A goggle search and indepth search of different forum did not yield any useful information.

Developers,users at stackflow, it will great if you can clear my doubt.

***additional information***

currently an individual developer and have a macbook air. Will be making apps like "recipe" and probably a health app and app like "we heart it"

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about shopping for iPhones, not programming.

Comment: hi! just wanted to know What role does a device plays (iphones and not simulators) when it comes developing and testing Iphone Apps??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your app do not use hardware related function，there is no need to buy latest iphone.
For example, if your app need to use BLE or touch ID,you have to use iphone/ipad support this.

Comment: thanks for the help. correct me if i am wrong. lets say i make an app and test it on my iphone 4 and later deploy it on the app store. the device  that currently i have is very slow in responding and processing takes a long time , so how will i know if it will work fine with other devices without any lag? I am sorry if its stupid question.

Comment: App runs on os, so you can update your iphone 4 to latest ios 8 system,then test your app.If it responds slowly,I suggest you to borrow or buy a new device to make sure that your app work fine.Actually if you work for a company,ask one form your manager